# How to expand disk space for standard user in kali linux?

Tags: linux, command-line, storage, kali-linux, open-source

I have two users in my linux device. I'm using kali rolling 2016 edition. 
I usually use my standard user profile.After installing some softwares it's showing that there is problem in storage available(It says"storage available low). I don't use root user normally.How to solve this?Is there any  way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your partition layout, as well as which partition is reporting as low. Check for the low storage available partition with `df -h`, then you'll most likely have to reboot into a LiveUSB environment and use gparted to easily (or parted if you prefer the challenge) to grow the full partition. BACK UP YOUR DATA FIRST.

Note that you'll most likely have to first shrink a neighboring partition first, then you can use the empty space to expand the other.